# Google Chrome Printing: Pages Settings - Set Default to Custom

Tags: google-chrome, printing, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a setting within Google Chrome version 74.0.3729.169 to always display the custom page range when selecting print or ctrl+p.
The default is set to "All" pages.  I would like it to already be set to "Custom".

I have looked in Chrome Settings, Chrome Flags, and Advanced Driver Settings with no luck.

I've been looking in Chrome Dev Tools but I am not too familiar with its use.

---

Update:
I figured out how to edit the HTML in Dev Tools to accomplish the layout I need. So how do I make those changes permanent? 
When I close the window the changes I have made are lost.

---

Update:
I was just informed that changes in DevTools are for testing and debugging, and that any changes made are not saved.

Still seeking an answer if anyone can contribute.